# Queries on Tree Path with Modifications

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, depth-first-search, lowest-common-ancestor

**Question:**

You are given a Tree with **n Nodes**(can be **upto 10^5**) and **n-1 bidirectional edges**. And lets say each node contains two values:

1. It's index(Just a unique number for node), lets say it will be from 1 to n.
2. And It's value **Vi**, which can vary from **1 to 10^8**

Now there will be multiple same type of queries(**number of queries can be upto 10^5**) on this same tree, as follows:

1. You are given node1, node2 and a value **P**(can vary from **1 to 10^8**).

And for every this type of query, you just have to find number of nodes in path from node1 to node2 whose value is **less than P**.

*NOTE: There will be unique path between all the nodes and no two edges belong to same pair of nodes.*

**Required Time Complexity O(nLog(n)) or can be in other terms but should be solvable in 1 Sec with given constraints.**

**What I have Tried:**

(A). I could solve it easily if value of P would be fixed, using LCA approach in O(nLog(n)) by storing following info at each node:

1. Number of nodes whose value is less than P, from root to given node.

But here P is varying way too much so this will not help.

(B). Other approach I was thinking is, using simple DFS. But that will also take O(nq), where q is number of queries. Again as n and q both are varying between 1 to 10^5 so this will not help too in given time constraint.

I could not think anything else. Any help would be appreciated. :)

**Source:**

I read this problem somewhere on SPOJ I guess. But cannot find it now. Tried searching it on Web but could not find solution for it anywhere (Codeforces, CodeChef, SPOJ, StackOverflow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Let `ans(v, P)` be the answer on a vertical path from the root to `v` and the given value of `P`.
2. How can we compute it? There's a simple offline solution: we can store all queries for the given node in a vector associated with it, run the depth-first search keep all values on the current path from the path in data structure that can do the following:

   - add a value
   - delete a value
   - count the number elements smaller than `X`

   Any balanced binary-search tree would do. You can make it even simpler: if you know all the queries beforehand, you can compress the numbers so that they're in the `[0..n - 1]` range and use a binary index tree.
3. Back to the original problem: the answer to a `(u, v, P)` query is clearly `ans(v, P) + ans(u, P) - 2 * ans(LCA(u, v), P)`.

That's it. The time complexity is `O((N + Q) log N)`.

Comment: Thanks for help buddy.. :) Can you also give me some link of problem like this? That will be really helpful.. :)